# how to disable user register in testlink

Tags: user-registration, testlink

I use bitnami-testlink-1.9.13-0-windows-installer.exe to install testlink.

how can I disable user registration then only admin can create new users in testlink.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK,I find the disable option in

testlinkfolder/apps/testlink/htdocs/config.inc.php

```
$tlCfg->user_self_signup = FALSE;
```

Comment: still valid as of 1.9.17